# Apply custom function to each row in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to apply a custom function I wrote to a dataframe in order to identify the closest airport given latitude and longitude. Here is the process and the code is below:

1. Dataframe consists of city, state, country, lat, long
2. Custom function uses the `airportr` package to identify the closest airport using lat and long as the function inputs
3. Output will be the city name and the IATA airport code.
4. Final result will be a data frame with city and airport codes.

When I run it using `apply`, I get the following error:

`Error in lat * pi : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

This makes me think `apply` is not pulling the data in correctly. Here is the code and a reprex:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(airportr)

locations <- tribble(~city, ~lat, ~long,

  
locations <- tribble(~city, ~lat, ~long,
                      "Philadelphia", 40.01, -75.1,
                      "Denver", 39.77, -104.87,
                      "Atlanta", 33.76, -84.42)

nearby <- function(x, output) {
  # access primary variables
  city = x[1]
  lat = x[2]
  long = x[3]
  # calculate closest airport
  airport <- airports_around(lat, long, distance=50) %>%
    select(Name, IATA, Latitude, Longitude) %>%
    # renove useless IATA codes
    filter(IATA != "\\N") %>%
    #calculates minmimum distance difference - probably a better way to do this
        mutate(lat_diff = Latitude-lat,
           long_diff = Longitude-long,
           sum = lat_diff+long_diff) %>%
    slice(which.min(sum)) %>%
    pull(IATA)
  #puts back together into a dataframe
  data.frame(city, airport)
}



#apply function
apply(locations, 1, nearby) -> tmp

#reform to a dataframe
data.frame(matrix(unlist(tmp), nrow=length(tmp), byrow=T))



#apply function
apply(locations %>% slice(1:10), 1, nearby) -> tmp

#reform to a dataframe
data.frame(matrix(unlist(tmp), nrow=length(tmp), byrow=T))
```

**UPDATE**
Based on a comment from  thelatemail, I was able to get it working by converting the columns to numeric first:

```
nearby <- function(x, output) {
  # access primary variables
  city = x[1]
  lat = x[2] %>% as.numeric()
  long = x[3] %>% as.numeric()
  # calculate closest airport
  airport <- airports_around(lat, long, distance=50) %>%
    select(Name, IATA, Latitude, Longitude) %>%
    # renove useless IATA codes
    filter(IATA != "\\N") %>%
    #calculates minmimum distance difference - probably a better way to do this
        mutate(lat_diff = Latitude-lat,
           long_diff = Longitude-long,
           sum = lat_diff+long_diff) %>%
    slice(which.min(sum)) %>%
    pull(IATA)
  #puts back together into a dataframe
  data.frame(city, airport)
}
```

Comment: Not sure how to solve this exact issue in dplyr world, but the issue is that `apply` converts the whole dataset to a `matrix` *first*, which means all your numbers become strings. That will then error out when you try to do any arithmetic on each row.

Comment: Well, that bit of knowledge allowed me to fix my function by adding `%>% as.numeric()` after each index call in the function!